# How is the job market for Chemistry like?

Tags: career-path, job, chemistry

Apologies if this isn't a correct website to ask. But I'm a UK student applying to study Chemistry at university mostly because I'm good at the subject and I enjoy learning the applications of what it can bring to us in the future like nanotechnology. I applied to UCL (Chemistry with Managment), Durham, Manchester, Bath and Warwick. I intend to get into a career in finance or IB possibly but not too sure yet.

I've recently decided to take a year off to see what I actually want to do with life and also just to relax after being burnt out over countless times and travel.

I think most of my problem is because of the fact that I take other people into account of chemistry and not just block them off.

So I just want to know what I can do with a Chemistry degree?

Comment: I suspect that this may be off-topic here since it's not really related to academia.

Comment: Haven't checked the figures, though I seem to recall that Bachelor's in Chemistry have a bit of trouble in the job market.  Usually they're more advisable as preparation for another degree, e.g. for a graduate degree in Chemistry or a professional degree in Medicine.  I guess the US patent office (USPTO) would probably accept it as a qualification to be a patent examiner, so there're specific careers like that.  Or if you're interested in finance, getting a graduate degree in a Business field might be a possibility.

Comment: In my (biased) opinion, you can't go wrong with a science subject. Have you asked your chemistry teacher for advice? How about your school's careers adviser? (I have voted to close your question as it's not about academia; a better place to ask it would be thestudentroom.co.uk)

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to your local job portal. It'll tell you more about what jobs are out there than most people can. Using Google for the term "uk job portal", I found these two sites: [jobsite.co.uk](http://www.jobsite.co.uk/) and [reed.co.uk](https://www.reed.co.uk/) (there are a lot of others). Search for positions requiring chemistry at your degree level (e.g. if you're applying for a PhD position, search for "PhD chemistry"). These job portals usually have lots of refine search options as well, such as sorting by location, salary, and so on.

I'd recommend subscribing and staying subscribed to these job alerts throughout your studies. Even if you never apply, at least you know what's out there, in case there's a change in market trends.